# How to deal with null values in C# from Access DB?

Tags: c#, ms-access, null

In my C# form I have address field in that i need to fill address that already DoorNo, Street, Area, Location are stored separately in Access Database. I used string concatenation to merge full address.

```
object row = CBL_Customer_Name.Properties.GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue(CBL_Customer_Name.EditValue) as object;

string getblocation = (row as DataRowView)["BLocation"].ToString();
string getbcity = (row as DataRowView)["BCity"].ToString();
string getbstate = (row as DataRowView)["BState"].ToString();
string getbcountry = (row as DataRowView)["BCountry"].ToString();

TXE_Invoice_Address.Text = (row as DataRowView)["BFlatNo"].ToString() + ", " + (row as DataRowView)["BPremises"].ToString() + "," + System.Environment.NewLine + (row as DataRowView)["BStreet"].ToString() + ", " + getloction(getblocation) + "," + System.Environment.NewLine + (row as DataRowView)["BArea"].ToString() + ", " + getcity(getbcity) + "," + System.Environment.NewLine + getstate(getbstate) + ", " + getcountry(getbcountry) + ".";
```

If user enter complete address then no problem in this above code. If he doesn't enter location or some other fields then am getting **`, ,`** or blank space in the end of line. 
How to solve this ? I need a perfect address in my address field if user leave 1 or 2 fields also.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.replace()` to replace empty values by a custom text.

**Example**

TXE_Invoice_Address.Text = TXE_Invoice_Address.Text.Replace(", ,", ", ")

This code will remove all `, ,` that may cause a strange adress format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `var newAddress = string.Join(", ",TXE_Invoice_Address.Text.Split(',').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));`

This will eliminate all empty spaces and rejoin to new a string.